# yii2 mailer mail not sent

Tags: yii2, mailer

There are absolutely two identical methods for sending mail (registration of a new user, **sending a letter to activate the user**). One method is implemented in the console, and it works:

```
public function actionSendMessage()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $this->readValue($user, 'username');
        $this->readValue($user, 'login');
        $this->readValue($user, 'email');
        $user->hash_password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->prompt('password'));
        $this->readValue($user, 'phone');
        $this->readValue($user, 'address');;
        $user->state = User::STATUS_WAIT;
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->generateEmailConfirmToken();
        if ($user->save()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/emailConfirm', ['user' => $user])
                ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name])
                ->setTo($user->email)
                ->setSubject('Email confirmation for ' . Yii::$app->name)
                ->send();
        }
    }
```

The second must send a letter when registering on the site, but alas, the letter does not come (**no errors**):

```
public function sign()
    {

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->login = $this->login;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->hash_password = yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
        $user->phone = $this->phone;
        $user->address = $this->address;
        $user->state = User::STATUS_WAIT;
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->generateEmailConfirmToken();
        if ($user->save()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/emailConfirm', ['user' => $user])
                ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name])
                ->setTo($user->email)
                ->setSubject('Email confirmation for ' . Yii::$app->name)
                ->send();
        }

    }
```

> In what there can be an error? `$user->save()` **is work** for both actions.

Comment: check if `->send()` returns true, and which app are you using `advanced` or `basic`   you need to add the config file too

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam 
Thanks for the response, I found the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to change the server settings in `web.php` for

```
transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => '****',
                'password' => '****',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
                ],
```

Letters formed, but did not send.